# How can I delete an unretrievable file from a Perforce repository?

Tags: linux, macos, perforce

In my Perforce repository there's a file that was submitted a while ago and was at one point valid.  I need to move the file and its parent directory to a different location in the repository.  However, I'm unable to retrieve a copy of the file from the repository due to the following error reported in P4V (2010.2) and p4 on Linux & Mac OS X:

```
Bad AppleSingle/Double header.
Malformed FInfo/FXInfo structure! File not updated.
```

The file is an Apple DMG (disk image) installer.  It appears that the file in the repository is corrupted and I'm unable to retrieve it.

Is it possible to retrieve the file regardless of errors in the file in the repository?

Is it possible to move the file in the repository without have a local copy of the file in my workspace?

Comment: How are you trying to move the files?  what command are you using or what GUI method are you using?

Comment: I've tried using the P4V GUI on Linux & Mac OS X with the same result when running "Get Latest Version".  I also tried using the command-line p4 client on Linux & Mac OS X with similar results.

Comment: Right.  But I'm asking what you did _specifically_ to try and move the files.  Did you try and use the 'p4 move' command, or the 'move/rename' option in p4v?

Comment: Here are the steps that I took in the P4V client:
Select Depot view
Select the file that's not being sync'd to my workspace
Single-right click on the file and choose 'Get Revision...'
Choose 'Get latest version'
Click OK
Encounter error message mentioned above.

I rarely use the p4 command-line client, so I tried it as a last resort.  I ran `p4 sync`, which failed with the same message mentioned earlier.

I was able to resolve this by rolling-back to an earlier revision of the file in the depot.  This is less desirable since one revision of the file is completely lost.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command line tool:

```
p4 delete -n //path/to/the/rotten/file
```

As long as your client maps //path/... you can delete things without fetching them (eg, don't do a `p4 sync` first)